# Writing the code correctly - Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi guys I have a table that shows all users registered on my website, no problem in selecting the checkboxes dynamically, I report the code of my table:

php:

```
<!--DELETE DATA CHECKBOX-->
<?php
session_start();
include '../a/connessione.php';
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
$checkbox = $_POST['check'];
for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++){
$del_id = $checkbox[$i]; 
$db ="DELETE FROM user WHERE id='".$del_id."'";
$q = mysqli_query($connessione, $db);
}
}
?>
<!--/DELETE DATA CHECKBOX-->
```

table:

```
<div class="px-4">  
<div class="table-wrapper">
<!--Table-->
<table class="table table-hover mb-0">
<!--Table head-->
<thead>
<tr>   
<th scope="row">   
</th>  
<th class="th-lg"><a>ID </a></th>
<th class="th-lg"><a href="">Nome</a></th>
<th class="th-lg"><a href="">Email</a></th>
<th class="th-lg"><a href="">Azioni</a></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<!--Table head-->

<!--Table body-->
<?php
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ ?>

<tbody>
<tr>
<th scope="row">
<input name="check[]" type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>">
<label   for="<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>" class="label-table"></label>
</th>
<td><?php echo $row['id'] ;?><br></td>
<td><?php echo $row['nome'] ;?><br></td>
<td><?php echo $row['email'] ;?><br></td>
<td><a href="#edit<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-outline-blue btn-rounded btn-sm px-2"> <i class="fa fa-info-circle mt-0"></i></a>  
<?php include('button.php'); ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>  
<?php } ?>   
<!--Table body-->
</table>
<!--Table-->
</div>

<hr class="my-0">

<!--Bottom Table UI-->
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
```

una foto:

[image]

my goal is to create a checkbox that selects all the other clicks, I bring the correct code to do this

code:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="js-selectall" data-target=".js-selectall1" />

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="js-selectall1" /> </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="js-selectall1" /> </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="js-selectall1" /> </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="js-selectall1" /> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="js-selectall1" /> </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="js-selectall1" /> </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="js-selectall1" /> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I can not write correctly and the code that allows me to create a checkbox that selects all the other clicks while having two codes written correctly, how can I do it?

My try :

```
<table class="table table-hover mb-0">
<!--Table head-->
<thead>
<tr>



<th scope="row">
<input type="checkbox" class="js-selectall" data-target=".js-selectall1" />
<label   for="#" class="label-table"></label>

</th>

<th class="th-lg"><a>ID </a></th>
<th class="th-lg"><a href="">Nome</a></th>
<th class="th-lg"><a href="">Email</a></th>
<th class="th-lg"><a href="">Azioni</a></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<!--Table head-->

<!--Table body-->
<?php
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ ?>

<tbody>
<tr>
<th scope="row">
<input name="check[]" class="js-selectall1" type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>">
<label   for="<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>" class="label-table"></label>
</th>
<td><?php echo $row['id'] ;?><br></td>
<td><?php echo $row['nome'] ;?><br></td>
<td><?php echo $row['email'] ;?><br></td>
<td><a href="#edit<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-outline-blue btn-rounded btn-sm px-2"> <i class="fa fa-info-circle mt-0"></i></a>  
<?php include('button.php'); ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>  
<?php } ?>   
<!--Table body-->
</table>
<!--Table-->
</div>


<script>
$('.js-selectall').on('change', function() {
  var isChecked = $(this).prop("checked");
  var selector = $(this).data('target');
  $(selector).prop("checked", isChecked);
});
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You need to put that code **under** the checkboxes or wrap it with `$(function() { <you code here>  });`

Comment: thank you Alon for your answer, you could give me a hand as I'm fasting on doing it

Comment: Not sure I understand. But you must also make sure that all that code be placed after `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I tried several times implementing an input and a label in my table as reported by the code I wrote later, making sure to put the scripts above all for a concept of correct execution

Comment: So you're really almost there, [check this](https://jsfiddle.net/0345rmmm/)

Comment: exactly, the only problem that I do not understand why even if I assign the correct class to the input of my checkbox in the table, and implementing input and relative lable, everything is not done correctly

Comment: Just a side note: be careful to sql injections, you should use PDO instead.

Comment: @User So i'm a bit confused because I don't see in your actual code any "Select All" checkbox, and I also don't see the `class="js-selectall1"` there. Do you have multiple tables or just the one?

Comment: great, in what way, give me some notions about what I should do well, for the search field for example as a precaution to use real_escape_string, on what should I be attending? I would be grateful if you showed it to me

Comment: I put a test but I can not make it work

Comment: Yes, because you need to move `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` and place it **after** the `<table></table>` element, and after that script you need to include your inline `<script>$('.js-selectall').on('change', function() {...</script>`

Comment: Modified but nothing, I put as I modified it in my application

Comment: No :) Like this: https://pastebin.com/f9C854sr

Comment: You guys are angels to help me I tried your code but it does not work !!!

Comment: Do you have this someone online so I can check what's going on? It doesn't make sense, it should work

Comment: put all my code: https://pastebin.com/GXgYFXCj

Comment: @User : regarding SQL injection : you are vulnerable where you use string concatenation to build the query string -- where you set `$db`.  You are making it from unfiltered input straight from `$_POST['check']`.  Your own HTML form will supply valid IDs, but someone could just POST to your PHP page independent of your HTML form, and supply anything they want in `$_POST['check']`, including nasty SQL that breaks out of the context of the statement you **intend** to execute, and instead execute a very different statement.  There is lots for you to read; start with PDO and 'parameter binding'.

Comment: YOU ARE REALLY WONDERFUL THAT GOD BLESS YOU, THANKS MANY, CAN THE FORTUNE COME IN YOUR LIFE

Comment: THIS IS THE ANSWER GUYS: http://jsfiddle.net/Dfzdh/

Comment: Great, so it's all working now?

Comment: YES ALON AND GUYS YOU WERE REALLY A BEAUTIFUL PERSON TO HAVE DEDICATED YOUR TIME TO MY QUESTION, HERE ALL IN THIS SITE ARE REALLY SPECIAL PEOPLE! REALLY!

the only thing that pulled me a bit 'down the tongue is the slq injection comment I would not have thrown all my work, would you recommend to program everything in laravel instead of php?

Comment: I was happy to help (Though the answer was in that duplicate eventually). About the [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) issue - You need to convert the code and use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), safe and easy. No need to convert it to laravel (Which is a php framework). Here is a full tutorial: https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: thank you, thank you so much, god can be in your life